# Does $R(L_1\cdot L_2)=L_2\cdot L_1$?

Tags: formal-languages

Does $R(L_1\cdot L_2)=L_2\cdot L_1$?

Where $R$ is the reverse.

I can't think about counter example

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really do that. In this case, there are counterexamples where $L_1$ and $L_2$ consist of just one word each, so you just need to think of words $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $R(w_1w_2)\neq w_2w_1$.

Comment: $R(L_1 \cdot L_2) = R(L_2) \cdot R(L_1)$ sounds more like it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to write $R(L_1⋅L_2)=R(L_2)⋅R(L_1)$? 
If so, then the answer is yes (prove it!).

The way your question is currently formulated, the answer is no: for example, take $L_1=\{ab\}$ and $L_2=\{b\}$.